# mssql_connect stops working after some time

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

I have a website that occacionally fails to connect to the database.
It starts by having problems on just a few page requests here and there, but after a while it just stops and can't connect at all. This is the error message I get:

> Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect
>   to server: localhost in
>   C:\wwwroot\x.se\root\classes\adodb5\drivers\adodb-mssql.inc.php on
>   line 520

If I restart Apache, it works fine again for a while - so it doesn't seem to be a problem with the dbserver. I tried to update the ntwdblib.dll but it didn't help.

This is the environment:

- Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition SP2
- PHP Version 5.2.9-2 Thread Safety enabled
- Apache 2.0.63 (Win32)
- MS SQL Server 2005

On top of this, due to various reasons, I can't just take this live server down for a couple of hours and reinstall stuff (well I guess I have to if all else fails). I will probably try to update PHP and/or Apache, but I'm looking for less invasive solutions to start with.

phpinfo() output:

- mssql
- MSSQL Support    enabled
- Active Persistent Links  1
- Active Links 1
- Library version  7.0
- Directive    Local Value Master Value
- mssql.allow_persistent   On  On
- mssql.batchsize  0   0
- mssql.compatability_mode Off Off
- mssql.connect_timeout    5   5
- mssql.datetimeconvert    On  On
- mssql.max_links  Unlimited   Unlimited
- mssql.max_persistent Unlimited   Unlimited
- mssql.max_procs  Unlimited   Unlimited
- mssql.min_error_severity 10  10
- mssql.min_message_severity   10  10
- mssql.secure_connection  Off Off
- mssql.textlimit  Server default  Server default
- mssql.textsize   Server default  Server default
- mssql.timeout    60  60

Upgraded ADODB from V5.06 (16 Oct 2008) to V5.15 (19 Jan 2012) didn't help either.

.. and upgrading the PHP stack from v5.2.9-2 (26 Feb 2009) to 5.2.17 (2011-Mar-22 13:29:30) didn't work.

Comment: Are you closing the connections every time after using it with a query?

Comment: Nope, I think PHP is supposed to do that itself after a page has been processed. Maybe I can try closing any open connections in the footer file that is included on all pages.

Comment: Can you try installing mtop and tell us what the server is up to?

Comment: Is there a MSSQL equivalent of mtop? I'm not too familiar with MSSQL, I guess it should have something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply turned off the mssql persistant connections in php.ini and now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using persistent connections? Might help if you are connecting often:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-pconnect.php

Comment: Looks like it is on already. I'm updating my post with the data.

Comment: It seems strange that it would be on but the server would still report a warning in "mssql_connect()" and not "mssql **_p** connect()"